# ImageMagick.MagickCoderErrorException: Failed to read directory at offset

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I have the following c# code:

```
private void BurstPdf(string tifName, string targetfolder)
{
    Console.WriteLine("BurstPdf({0}, {1})", tifName, targetfolder);

    using (MagickImageCollection tiffPageCollection = new MagickImageCollection())
    {
        tiffPageCollection.Read(tifName);    // Fails on this line.
```

It produces the following runtime error:

```
Unhandled Exception: ImageMagick.MagickCoderErrorException: Failed to read directory at offset 51038729. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/645
  at ImageMagick.MagickImageCollection.NativeMagickImageCollection.ReadFile(MagickSettings settings)
  at ImageMagick.MagickImageCollection.AddImages(String fileName, MagickReadSettings readSettings, Boolean ping)
  at ImageMagick.MagickImageCollection.Read(String fileName)
```

Here is what I have tried to find a solution to this problem:

1. Added the Console.WriteLine and painfully confirmed the file exists.  Also, the file originates from a `Directory.GetFiles()` so it is code that specifies the filename.
2. Googled for the error message.  There are similar errors saying the file is corrupt.
3. I open the file in MS Paint to confirm it is not corrupt.
4. I can see the thumbnail in Windows explorer indicating it is not corrupt.
5. I can open the file in Windows Photo Viewer indicating it is not corrupt.
6. I copied the file to a Mac and it displays the .tif as all black and the finder thumbnail is all black.  There are many people claiming this is a bug in preview.
7. I opened the file in "Get Info" on my mac and it will display the thumbnail.  it reports it as a 5100x6600 Gray filed with no alpha channel.  It is a 65MB file

We produce other files with this same technique (printing to the printer driver configured to output a .tif rather than print and are able to read them with imagemagick.  However, they are not as large.

How do I get this file to read in imagemagick?

[EDIT]
I tried a second file that is 22MB and it fails with this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: ImageMagick.MagickCoderErrorException: Not enough data at scanline 6599 (short 1229 bytes). `LZWDecode' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/645
  at ImageMagick.MagickImageCollection.NativeMagickImageCollection.ReadFile(MagickSettings settings)
  at ImageMagick.MagickImageCollection.AddImages(String fileName, MagickReadSettings readSettings, Boolean ping)
  at ImageMagick.MagickImageCollection.Read(String fileName)
```

That looks like a message I would expect with a corrupt file, but it is able to viewed the same as the other larger file.

Comment: This question has a chunk of code, and error message, and the things I have tried to fix the error.  I think this is an ideal question for stack.  If you downvote please list a reason why.

Comment: I would try using a copy of the file, and try opening the file with something like GIMP to see if it gives any warning, and re-exporting the file. My hypothesis is that the files have an error in the compression, but one from which it is possible to recover… Except ImageMagick is not doing it. Anyway, I would not expect to get a good answer here, in particular without the images to test. Besides, this looks like something you should report as a bug or ask the developers. No, I did not down vote.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to repair the .tif files by using Windows Photo Viewer to print the file to a .pdf.  Then using preview on a Mac to export the file as a .tif.

It is important to set the print option to NOT sharpen the picture otherwise the barcodes on the page are obscured.

I changed the DPI on the file when I exported it to ensure that it was re-encoding the file.